# Issues with running xgboost in multiple R processes

Tags: r, parallel-processing, xgboost

Are there any known issues with running xgboost in multiple R processes simultaneously?

The background is that I'm trying to do a simple grid search for the best hyperparameters. Since I have several cores on this machine, I thought I'd run the models in parallel. However, `xgb.DMatrix` dies with an error:

```
> cl <- makeCluster(4)
> clusterEvalQ(cl, {
+     load("processed_data.rdata")
+     library(xgboost)
+     traindata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(train_df), label=train_y)
+     testdata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(test_df), label=test_y)
+ })
[[1]]
Error in dim.xgb.DMatrix(x) :
  [12:59:39] amalgamation/../src/c_api/c_api.cc:355: DMatrix/Booster has not been intialized or has already been disposed.
```

It looks like trying to load the xgboost code into multiple processes is not allowed. Is this correct? If so, what is the best way to conduct a parallelised grid search?

My session info:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods
[8] base

other attached packages:
[1] purrr_0.3.4     xgboost_1.2.0.1 tidyr_1.1.2     dplyr_1.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_2.0.1    tidyselect_1.1.0  lattice_0.20-41   R6_2.5.0
 [5] rlang_0.4.9       fansi_0.4.1       tools_4.0.3       grid_4.0.3
 [9] data.table_1.13.2 utf8_1.1.4        cli_2.2.0         ellipsis_0.3.1
[13] assertthat_0.2.1  tibble_3.0.4      lifecycle_0.2.0   crayon_1.3.4     
[17] Matrix_1.2-18     vctrs_0.3.5       glue_1.4.2        stringi_1.5.3    
[21] compiler_4.0.3    pillar_1.4.7      generics_0.1.0    pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. What happens is that `clusterEvalQ`, per convention in R, uses the value of the last evaluated expression as the returned value to the head node. This is done by serialising the value into the pipeline between worker and head, and then deserialising it again. However, an `xgb.DMatrix` cannot be serialised like a regular R object, since it contains external pointers; trying to deserialise it causes the error.

The solution is for the expression passed to `clusterEvalQ` to have anything other than an `xgb.DMatrix` call as its last line. `NULL` will do:

```
> clusterEvalQ(cl, {
+     load(file.path(local_dir, "processed_data.rdata")
+     library(xgboost)
+     traindata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(train_df), label=train_y)
+     testdata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(test_df), label=test_y)
+     NULL
+ })
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `)` on the load() line. Else,

Maybe it would work to split up the task into discrete steps?

```
library(xgboost)
load("processed_data.rdata")
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  traindata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(train_df), label=train_y)
})
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  testdata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(test_df), label=test_y)
})
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, fixed

Comment: Also, having only one `xgb.DMatrix` call in `clusterEvalQ` still results in the same error

Comment: Looks like this blogger got parallel bagging to work - maybe something on this page will help! https://sites.google.com/site/lauraeppx/xgboost/parallel-bagging

Comment: I'm basically doing the exact same thing as far as loading the data goes, so I don't know why it's not working